# CCNet queue not working

Tags: queue, cruisecontrol.net

I have defined a CCNet queue which is included in several CI projects (about 10).

The queue fills up and I can see pending jobs in CCTray and in the dashboard, which are correctly ordered based on the priorities I have defined.  However, the queue is emptied as soon as the first job completes, and the dashboard activity of all jobs that were "Pending" returns to "Sleeping".

I do not have triggers between projects - the only trigger I am using in any project is for starting a build if the source repository is updated.

```
<queue name="myQ" duplicates="ApplyForceBuildsReplace" />

<cb:scope ProjectName="My project">

      <project category="MyProjects" name="$(ProjectName)" queue="myQ" queuePriority="1" webURL="$(WebUrl)" workingDirectory="c:\my_project\work" artifactDirectory="c:\my_project\log" >

        <triggers>
          <intervalTrigger name="continuous integration" seconds="120" buildCondition="IfModificationExists"/>
        </triggers>

        <sourcecontrol type="filtered">
            <sourceControlProvider type="vsts">
                <server>$(TeamProjectCollectionUrl)</server>
                <project>$/MyProject</project>
                <workingDirectory>c:\my_project_work_tfs</workingDirectory>
                <workspace>my_project_work_tfs</workspace>
                <deleteWorkspace>false</deleteWorkspace>
            </sourceControlProvider>
        </sourcecontrol>

        <tasks>
          <exec>
            [invokes NAnt...]
          </exec>
        </tasks>

      </project>
    </cb:scope>
```

Three of my projects have a priority of 1 and the others have a priority 2.

I am using CCNet 1.8.3.0.

Can anyone help?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

From your question I read that you expect the projects to build after the first one is triggered, yes? In that case you need to include a project trigger for every project that gets triggered as soon as its dependency gets triggered.